# How do I delete all .webp files in a directory based on if the duplicate .jpeg file (with the same .BaseName) has changed in the last 24 hours?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

So, I have a directory of pictures for a website. There are pictures that are the same with both a `.jpeg` extension and a `.webp` extension. I want to write a PowerShell script that finds all the existing `.jpeg` files that changed in the last 24 hours, and then find the respective `.webp` file and delete the `.webp` file.

I've tried this to get all the `.webp` files that can be deleted but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$images = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir\*.jpg, $dir\*.webp | 
Group-Object { $_.BaseName } |
    Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) -or ($_.Group.Extension -notcontains '.jpg')} | 
        ForEach-Object Group
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is easier:

Get a list of basenames for the jpg files that were last modified as of yesterday, next get a list of files in the same directory with the .webp extension that have a BaseName matching one of the jpg basenames and then remove these.

```
$dir     = 'D:\Test'
$refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
$jpegs   = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.jpg' -File | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $refdate }).BaseName
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.webp' -File | Where-Object { $jpegs -contains $_.BaseName } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Onece you are satisfied the correct files are getting deleted, remove the safety `-WhatIf` switch and run again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It doesn't see to work though. It doesnt seem to target the right files. I think I made a mistake with my explanation. The target property that should be filtered is the "Created in the last 24 hours", if there is a .webp that for that file, that .webp should be deleted.

Comment: the $refdate seems to target the "Changed in the last 24 hours", how should I correct this?

Comment: @HajoBrandt No problem, if you want to look at `CreationTime` rather than the last modified date, change `$_.LastWriteTime` into `$_.CreationTime`

Answer (score 1):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65684903/45375) shows you an alternative approach; if you want to stick with the [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) approach:

```
$webpFilesToDelete = 
  Get-ChildItem -Path $dir\*.jpg, $dir\*.webp | 
    Group-Object BaseName | Where-Object Count -eq 2 |
      ForEach-Object {
        # Test the creation date of the *.jpg file.
        if ($_.Group[0].CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)) {
          $_.Group[1] # Output the corresponding *.webp file
        }
      }
```

- Note that, as in your own attempt, `.CreationTime` is used, though note if there's a chance that the files are updated again *after* creation and that is the timestamp you care about, you should use `.LastWriteTime`.
- The command relies on the fact that `Group-Object` sorts the elements of the groups it creates by the sort criteria, which in this case, due to grouping by a *string* property - means lexical sorting in which `.jpg` files are listed before `.webp` files.
- Therefore, for groups that have 2 elements (`Where-Object Count -eq 2`), implying that for the given base name both a `.jpg` and a `.webp` file exist, `$_.Group[0]` refers to the `.jpg` file, and `$_.Group[1]` to the `.webp` file.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$_.CreationTime` yields `$null`, because `$_` in your command refers to the *group-information* object at hand (an instance of [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupInfo)), as output by `Group-Object`, and this type has no such property.
- Also, since you're using `Where-Object`, you're simply *filtering* groups, so that any group that passes the filter tests is passed through as-is, and `ForEach-Object Group` then outputs *both* files in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your helpfull answers and the clarification! I thougth initially that I needed .LastWriteTime, but I needed .CreationTime. This serves my needes. Here is the result:

```
$refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
$jpegs   = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.jpg' -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $refdate }).BaseName
$webp = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.webp' -File | Where-Object { $jpegs -contains $_.BaseName }
```